# Repair tree-drop-caused compressed depression in lawn

Tags: lawn-repair, tree-removal

Had a tree dropped on my lawn and now there is a pretty noticeable depression.  They actually had a log there, for the dropped tree to land on.  But then that log pushed down.  Depression is sort of hemispherical and 5 inches deep/wide, four feet long.  Is in my lawn.

Note, I'm not looking for a pool table flat surface; don't mind some natural look to my lawn.

Advice on how to address?

1. Leave it as is and a science experiment if it evens out with rest of lawn eventually?
2. Fill with dirt and throw some grass seed on?
3. Excavate general area and smush the dirt to similar height?  (But this means tearing up more of my lawn.)
4. Other.

P.s.  Mea culpa in advance if this is too obvious/easy a question.  I'm not very toolsy, knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave it as is you get a trip hazard and mower trap.  Let's rule that out.

Next easiest solution assumes you have a spade, some topsoil, hose and maybe a bit of grass seed.

Use the spade to cut a line parallel to the dip that is at least four inches deep. Then roll the grass and soil in the dip out.  Be careful as you want to reuse the grass.

The fill in the dip with topsoil and return the grass to the area.  Add some grass seed, water in for a few days or longer if it is dry and job done

Comment: Makes sense and not that arduous.  I guess I gotta go buy grass seed.  But they must sell that at nurseries or home despot.  Never noticed it, but would think.  Could use the rest of the bag elsewhere.  Don't have one of those rolly seeder things (mine rusted out years ago.  Maybe I do it by hand or buy a new one of those also.  Probably wrong time of year to seed. But who cares.  I guess one thing I was wondering is the compression to that spot (obviously soil more compressed).  But who cares on that also.